# PL/SQL Blocks - seeing output simply ? [A Very simple question I'm sure !]

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I'm sure what I want is very simple but I cannot figure out how.

I want :

- To declare some variables and initialize them to certain values
- To excecute a number of selects (predicated by the above variable values) and see the results as if i had executed the results straight on the sqlplus command line

I believe it's necessary to use the block structure in order that I may declare and make use of variables within the predicates of the queries. Although the examples shown here are quite simple in the real case there are numberous, much more complex SELECT's.

I tried doing this (forgetting about predicates for a moment) ...

```
DECLARE
    EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID_IN  VARCHAR2(12);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM DEPT WHERE DEPNO';
END;
/
```

... but when I do that I get to execute the select without seeing the output.

I've also tried this ...

```
DECLARE
    EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID_IN  VARCHAR2(12);
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM DEPT;
END;
/
```

... but then I get ...

PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

... I really don't want to have to declare a variable for every column which would appear in my output.

Can anyone tell me how I can execute the SELECTs but simply and easily see the output as if I were on the sqlplus command line, ie to see the same output as if I did this

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DEPT;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Thanks

---

---

I have now tested the answer given by Shannon Severance below and found that it will do what I want.

For the sake of later readers I thought it might be useful to show the complete script here.

```
set line 32000;
set trimspool on;
var V_CURSOR1 REFCURSOR;
var V_CURSOR2 REFCURSOR;
var V_CURSOR3 REFCURSOR;
DECLARE
    DEPT_NUM_IN     VARCHAR2(12);
BEGIN
    DEPT_NUM_IN :=  '10';
    OPEN :V_CURSOR1 FOR SELECT * FROM DEPT;
    OPEN :V_CURSOR2 FOR SELECT * FROM DEPT ORDER BY LOC;
    OPEN :V_CURSOR3 FOR SELECT * FROM DEPT WHERE DEPTNO = DEPT_NUM_IN ORDER BY LOC;
END;
/
print V_CURSOR1
print V_CURSOR2
print V_CURSOR3
```

Comment: "see the result as if..." is not how PL/SQL Blocks work... it is absolutely not clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @Yahia - thanks for your comment I will edit the question to make clearer

Comment: It is still not clearer - as I said "PL/SQL Blocks" are something really different - why don't you just execute the SELECTs without a PL/SQL Block ?

Comment: @Yahia - thanks for your comment. I will edit the question again to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From sqlplus, other tools may be different.

First declare a sqlplus refcursor variable

```
SQL> var l_cursor refcursor
```

Then open that cursor within a PL/SQL block, where you will have access to declared variables and everything:

```
SQL> edit
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2      l_number number;
  3  begin
  4      open :l_cursor for select table_name from all_tables where rownum < 10;
  5* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Notice above that the refcursor variable is prepended with a `:`, this is because we are binding a sqlplus variable into the PL/SQL anonymous block

Next, use the SQLPLUS print command:

```
SQL> print l_cursor

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
ICOL$
CON$
UNDO$
PROXY_ROLE_DATA$
FILE$
UET$
IND$
SEG$
COL$

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Shannon. I have added the code I wrote to test your answer within my own context to the question to allow later readers to see a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  v_result VARCHAR2(400);

BEGIN

  SELECT dummy
    INTO v_result
    FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try this but using "SELECT * INTO v_result FROM EMP;" ... Oracle said ... "PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values".

Comment: @gloucon, you would have had to define v_result as a record of emp%RECORDTYPE and then dbms_output the individual fields.

Comment: @glaucon define v_result and everything will be ok. see comment of Shannon Severance

Comment: @Shannon Severance : Thanks for your suggestions. In fact the queries I had in mind came from very large views (many columns) and were of the form 'select c1, c2, c3, ... cn from v1' and so it wouldn't be practical to use v1%RECORDTYPE. I appreciate my examples didn't reflect that level of complexity but I was trying to keep things simple ! Anyway I think for my purposes Shannon Severance approach of using refcursors works best . Thanks again.

Comment: @Tvitmsvleli: For some odd reason StackOverflow wouldn't allow me to refer to both you and Shannon Severanance in the previous comment . So I'm mentioning you in this comment so that if you're email notifications turned on you can read the comment above which was intended for you as much as it was for Shannon Severance. Hope that makes some sort of sense !